# How can I call a method from onSubmit functon in Vue?

Tags: typescript, forms, vue.js, store, onsubmit

I have a button that is used to log in the user via onSubmit function when a form is filled in. However, I need to call yet another method that will get some additional data about the user, such as privileges. However I cannot make it to work. I've tried to put the code from desired method directly in the onSubmit() function, but it did not work. Here is my code:

This is the form where the button is located.

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
 Some code
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

This is my script.

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, reactive} from 'vue'
import userStore from '../store/user'
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const form = reactive({
      username: "",
      password: "",
    });

    //Calls the login function in user.ts
    const onSubmit = () => {
      userStore.login(form.username, form.password);
      form.username = "";
      form.password = "";
    };

        //Returns the store in the main so that the form can have a template that displays the error message.
        return {form, userStore, onSubmit}
    },
    methods:{
        //This did not work. useStore could not be accessed from "methods" but could be accessed from setup/mounted. 
        //The thing is, it must be updated only after clickig on the submit button. 
        setUserState(){
            const store = useStore();
            store.dispatch("setActiveUser");
        },

    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Use `this.$store` instead of `useStore()` if you are not using the [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) and actually use `methods`. In your case, you are mixing both `setup` and `methods`. Don't use `methods` at all, if you are using Composition API. You can return the method in the setup function (like a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found the solution to my problem. I moved setUserState() as a function under setup() and deleted the methods. Setup is setting up the store now and returns setUserState. Following code works:

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, reactive} from 'vue'
import userStore from '../store/user'
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const form = reactive({
      username: "",
      password: "",
    });

    //Calls the login function in user.ts
    function onSubmit() {
      userStore.login(form.username, form.password);
      form.username = "";
      form.password = "";

      setUserState()
    }

    function setUserState(){
      store.dispatch("setActiveUser");
    }

        //Returns the store in the main so that the form can have a template that displays the error message.
    return {form, userStore, onSubmit, setUserState}
    },
})
</script>
```